# Recurring figures are not on same position - latex beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, overlays

I have the following problem with my latex presentation: After a reinstallation of Texniccenter recurring Figures are not on the same position anymore (small shift to the right). Before everything worked fine, my file is also working on other computers.

Miniexample:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textbf{test}}
\begin{figure}
\vspace{-2.15cm}
\hspace{-1.1cm} 
\includegraphics<1>[width=0.6\columnwidth]{test.jpg}
\includegraphics<2>[width=0.6\columnwidth]{test.jpg}
\includegraphics<3>[width=0.6\columnwidth]{test.jpg}
\includegraphics<4>[width=0.6\columnwidth]{test.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space from the newline between the `\includegraphics`-lines seem to be included, add a `%` at the end of the first three lines.

On Overleaf (which has TeX Live 2016, `beamer` version 2015/01/05 3.36) it works without the `%`. On my system (TeX Live 2017, `beamer` version 2017/08/22 v3.43) it doesn't. I would guess a change in `beamer` is the cause, but it could also be something else that has changed.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textbf{test}}
\begin{figure}
\vspace{-2.15cm}
\hspace{-1.1cm} 
\includegraphics<1>[width=0.6\columnwidth]{test.jpg}%
\includegraphics<2>[width=0.6\columnwidth]{test.jpg}%
\includegraphics<3>[width=0.6\columnwidth]{test.jpg}%
\includegraphics<4>[width=0.6\columnwidth]{test.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa I didn't. The OP says this used to work, so possibly there has been some change in `beamer` recently. (I'm on up-to-date TL17, `beamer` 2017/08/22 v3.43.)